# A proof about $Z(A_n) = \{ e \}, \forall n \geq 4$..

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I have to demonstrate that:

> Show $Z(A_n) = \{ e \}, \forall n \geq 4$.

I think I solved this problem, but I am not sure. This is my solution:

> Let's say $Z(A_n) \neq \{ e \}, \forall n \geq 4$. Then I have two cases:
>
> 1) $n = 2k, k \in \Bbb Z$
>
> 2) $n = 2k+1, k \in \Bbb Z$.
>
> I tried only case 1), I think case 2) work the same as well.
>     I choose:
>   $$a =   \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 & n\\
>     2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n-1  & 1 & n
>   \end{pmatrix},$$ where $a \in Z(A_n)$
>   and
>   $$\sigma =   \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & i & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
>     2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & i+1 & \cdots & n & 1
>   \end{pmatrix},$$ where $\sigma \in A_n.$
>
> Then we have $a(\sigma(n-1)) = a(n) = n$ and $\sigma(a(n-1)) = \sigma(1)=2$ so $a(\sigma(1)) \neq \sigma(a(2))$, contradiction.

Comment: why should $a\in Z(A_n)$ have the form $(1,n-1)$?

Comment: $a =   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & n-2 & n-1 & n\\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots &  n-1  & 1 & n
  \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\sigma =   \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & i & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
    2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & i+1 & \cdots & n & 1
  \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @Alessandro I use absurd to say $Z(A_n) \neq \{ e \}$..

Comment: then you should edit the question, because $a=(1,n-1)$ means the permutation of $1$ with $n-1$, the one you mean is $a=(1,2,\cdots,n-1)$

Comment: furthermore, you prove that $a=(1,\cdots,n-1)$ cannot belong to $Z(A_n)$ since it doesn't commute with $\sigma$

Comment: Edited now, sorry. Tell me if it's correct this proof or not..

Comment: I just tried to addapt from general case $S_n$ but every transposition is even so that proof (from S_n) not work..

Comment: Why should $a$ have this specific form ?

Comment: @Carot Because $a$ to be from $A_n$ and to get the contradiction.

Comment: @stricknycu, the proof is not correct, since as already pointed out, $a$ need not have the form you stated, and if $n$ is odd, then $a=(1,2,\cdots,n-1)$ is not even an element of $A_n$

Comment: I said is only for $n$ even.

Comment: But $(1,2)(3,4)$ is in $A_4$ and not of this form.

Comment: Idk, it's just a try. If you have another ideea tell me.

Comment: Thank you for showing your attempt. Your mistake is in how you follow the structure of proof by contradiction. You assume $Z(A_n)$ is non-trivial, this is good. Using only this (and other things you know to be true) you must find a contradiction. Your assumption on $a$ is not something you know to be true so the proof is not complete. What you have shown is that $a\notin Z(A_n)$.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why the other answer had a -1 as it looks correct to me, but I'll give a hint of slightly faster proof:

Suppose $1\ne\sigma\in Z(A_n)$ so there is some $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $\sigma(i)\ne i$.

Choose some $\rho\in A_n$ with $\rho(i)=i$ and $\rho(\sigma(i))\ne\sigma(i)$. Use $(\rho\sigma\rho^{-1})(i)$ to show $\rho\sigma\rho^{-1}\ne\sigma$ completing the proof by contradiction.

Comment: Whoever is putting -1 on all the answers, please explain why so we can provide an answer closer to what you would like.

Answer (score 2):

My solution its the next: Remember that if $\alpha, \beta \in S_{n}$ and $\beta$ has the descompocition in disjoin cyles $\beta = (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k})(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{l}) \cdots (z_{1}, \ldots, z_{m})$ then $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (\ \alpha(x_{1}), \ldots, \alpha(x_{k})\ )(\ \alpha(y_{1}), \ldots, \alpha(y_{l})\ ) \cdots (\ \alpha((z_{1}), \ldots, \alpha(z_{m})\ )$.

Let $\sigma \in A_{n}$, $\sigma \neq id$ with descompocition in disjoin cycles $(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k})(y_{1}, \ldots, y_{l}) \cdots (z_{1}, \ldots, z_{m})$.

Case 1) There are two non-trivial cycles $ (x_{1}, \ldots, x_{k})$ and $ (y_{1}, \ldots, y_{l}) $ then $ x_{1}, x_{ 2}, y_{1}, y_{2} $ are different from each other. If $\tau = (x_{1},y_{1},y_{2})$ you get that:
\begin{equation*}
\tau \sigma \tau^{-1} = (y_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, \ldots)(y_{2}, x_{1}, y_{3}) \neq \sigma
\end{equation*}
The other case is similar and the same idea is used.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another try.   Since $Z(A_n)\triangleleft A_n$,  and for $n\ge5$ we have $A_n$ simple, we are done in this case.

If $n=4$, we need to do something else.  If you study $A_4$,  its only normal subgroup turns out to be $\{e, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$..  But, for instance,  $(13)(14)(12)(34)=(124)\ne(132)=(12)(34)(13)(14)$.  So the center must be trivial.

Comment: What means "we have $A_n$ simple"?

Comment: A _simple_ group has no nontrivial normal subgroups.  It is a very famous result of Camille Jordan that $A_n$ is simple when $n\gt4$.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select $\sigma\in Z(A_n)$, since $n\geqslant 4$ take the even 3-cycles $(1,2,3)$. Now, take $\sigma(1,2,3)\sigma^{-1}=(1,2,3)$, then for $\sigma(1)$, $\sigma(1,2,3)\sigma^{-1}$ returns $\sigma(2)$ and so $(1,2,3)$ must send $\sigma(1)$ to $\sigma(2)$ and since $(1,2,3)$ move only $1,2,3$ we conclude $\sigma(1)\in \{1,2,3\}$. Using $(1,2,4)$ instead of $(1,2,3)$ we conclude in the same way as before that $\sigma(1)\in\{1,2,4\}$, and finally using $(1,4,3)$, $\sigma(1)\in\{1,3,4\}$, so $$\sigma(1)\in\{1,2,3\}\cap\{1,2,4\}\cap\{1,3,4\}=\{1\}\rightarrow \sigma(1)=1$$ in the same way you can prove that $\sigma(i)=i$, for $i=2,\cdots,n$, thus $\sigma=e$